# ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/3/Frames/RTMP_sid_afb5_1?row_count=10)

Tags: java, r, windows, eclipse, h2o

I installed H2o (3.4), Java SE SDK (17), and use R (4.1.3). I am working on deep autoencoder. I was able to split my data using SplitFrame and generated autoencoder model and everything was working well. A week later, when I was working with the same data to regenerate my model because I didn't save my workspace, I had to split again, and then the following error came up. I have been battling with it for 3 days now. See the error below:

`ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/3/Frames/RTMP_sid_afb5_1?row_count=10)`

````
water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException: Object 'RTMP_sid_afb5_1' not found for argument: key"      
 [2] "    water.api.FramesHandler.getFromDKV(FramesHandler.java:136)"                                              
 [3] "    water.api.FramesHandler.doFetch(FramesHandler.java:226)"                                                 
 [4] "    water.api.FramesHandler.doFetch(FramesHandler.java:221)"                                                 
 [5] "    water.api.FramesHandler.fetch(FramesHandler.java:200)"                                                   
 [6] "    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                          
 [7] "    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)"        
 [8] "    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
 [9] "    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)"                                              
[10] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:60)"                                                               
[11] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:472)"                                                   
[12] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:303)"                                               
[13] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGet(RequestServer.java:225)"                                                   
[14] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)"                                            
[15] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)"                                            
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)"                                  
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)"                              
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)"                       
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)"                      
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)"                        
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)"                               
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)"                        
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)"                       
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)"                           
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)"                   
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)"                         
[27] "    water.webserver.jetty9.Jetty9ServerAdapter$LoginHandler.handle(Jetty9ServerAdapter.java:130)"            
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)"                   
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)"                         
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)"                                                 
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)"                                       
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)"                             
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)"             
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)"                                       
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)"                                    
[36] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)"                  
[37] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)"                
[38] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)"               
[39] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)"                      
[40] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)"
[41] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)"                        
[42] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)"                         
[43] "    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)"                                                         

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  

ERROR MESSAGE:

Object 'RTMP_sid_afb5_1' not found for argument: key```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. I had to convert the dataset again to an h2o object before calling the splitFrame function.

```
trans_hf <- as.h2o(atm_trans)
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(trans_hf, ratios = c(0.4, 0.4), seed = 42)
```

I don't know why I had to do that because the trans_hf was not empty nor null but it is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

The function call h2o.splitFrame works only on h2o frame.  That is why you need to convert to an h2o object before calling the splitFrame function.  Thank you for figuring this one out.